# Replace tile picures in Google maps API getTile override

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm doing an application, where you can click on a google maps tile, and replace it with another picture.

The current solution is that I added an overlay map, and overrode the getTile(), to create a custom div with an ID, and a click event listener, where I can select it with ID selector, and work with it.

The current solution is (summed up):

```
CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
 var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');
 div.id = 'block_' + coord.x + '_' + coord.y;
 return div;
};

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
 var coord = ... the current tile coordinate
 var block_to_select = $('#block_' + coord.x + '_' + coord.y);
 do_magic(block_to_select);
}
```

It would be better to add the click event listener in the gettile() so I could get rid of the IDs, and a lot of computing code.

I tried:

```
CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
 var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');
 div.dataset.x = coord.x;
 div.addEventListener('click',function(){
    alert(1);
 });
 return div;
}
```

But it the onclick function won't run.

Is there any more efficient way to replace tile pictures?

Returning a jquery  $("") also throws error in getTile().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tiles will be rendered in the [`overlayLayer`-mapPane](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes) .

According to the documentation this mapPane may not receive DOM-events, so I'm afraid there is no better way than detecting a particular tile via a calculation.